# Why do projects in the quantlib solution look for the older version of quantlib.lib to link with?

Tags: c++, linker, quantlib

I was able to build the Quantlib project. However, for some reason, building CDS and other projects in the QuantLib solution failed for the following error message.

> LNK1104   cannot open file 'QuantLib-vc110-mt-gd.lib' CDS

I am using vs2015 and have quantlib built under the name QuantLib-vc140-mt-gd.lib, but somehow the CDS project manages to look for an older QuantLib lib.

I also added the following block of code to auto_link.hpp of quantlib.

> #elif (_MSC_VER == 1900)
>
> #  define QL_LIB_TOOLSET "vc140"

Comment: Is it possible that you still have some files compiled with an older version of the compiler?  Does the error still appear if you do a clean build?